# In Quarto, plot dim get doubled when rendered as HTML compared to `ragg` PNG output with same value for resolution and size

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, r-markdown, quarto

I tried to understand why size of the two output plots in below r chunks of my qmd file are different (HTML get doubled the dimension of `agg_png`). I think they should be the same since `size` and `res` are the same (or not?). I added screenshots to illustrate the point.

Thanks in advance for any advice and help on my problem.

````
---
title: "q1"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(ragg)
library(palmerpenguins)

p <- ggplot(na.omit(penguins), aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(color = species, shape = species),
    size = 3,
    alpha = 0.8
  )

pngfile <- fs::path(knitr::fig_path(),  "basis.png")
agg_png(pngfile, width = 7.8, height = 4.68, units = "in", res = 300)
plot(p)
invisible(dev.off())
```

```{r}
#| label: eight-plot
#| message: false
#| warning: false
#| fig-width: 7.8
#| fig-height: 4.68
#| fig-dpi: 300
#| fig-align: center
#| out-width: "70%"
p

```
````

[image]
[image]